# Linux Save session

Tags: linux, terminal

I did some work on AWS to install R on Redhat and I want to save what I have done there and hand over to my coworker. I know I can do:

```
history > file.txt
```

But I vaguely remember there is a cool command in linux so you can save your session somehow. Any clue?

It is used to save home work to the professor?

Answer (score 0):

The unix [script](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?script) command will let you save your terminal session into a file.